# Clojure reducers - efficiently apply function to two vectors in parrallel

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

What is the most efficient and idiomatic way to combine two or more large vectors together?  This is what I have been doing.  In my application I'm using matrices, so each operation is a bit more expensive than adding two doubles.  Using `range` to drive the fold feels a bit clumsy.

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(def a (mapv (fn [_] (rand 100)) (range 100000)))
(def b (mapv (fn [_] (rand 100)) (range 100000)))
(r/foldcat (r/map #(+ (a %) (b %)) (range (count a))))
```

Also calculating that `range` could end up being the most costly bit on multi-core CPUs since it's the only non-parallel part and involve sequences.

Comment: I assume it's `mapv` instead of `vmap`?

Comment: Are a and b actually matrices instead of vectors?

Comment: Can you describe the shape of your data and actual computation further? It's possible something like core.matrix may be a better fit.

Comment: Yes `mapv`.  I am using core.matrix ( vectorz-clj ).   Typically I have one vector of 3x3 matrices and another of vector3's and I need to multiply them together in a pairwise manner, like the pattern I presented here.  This is for a large computational dynamics problem.  There may be 100k elements in each vector, so parallelism is greatly desired.  Also I'm using clojure for prototyping because I can develop and experiment much more efficiently in Clojure.  So I do want to keep things simple and take advantage of conveniences like core.reducers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually looks like Clojure 1.8 has a pretty good answer, with the pattern in place already in Clojure 1.7 using `map-index`.

Ideally I'd like a `map-index` that takes multiple collections like `map` does, but this will do. It looks fairly clojuresque, unlike my kludgy fold over a range.

```
(defn combine-with [op a-coll] (fn [i b-el] (op (a-coll i) b-el)))

(map-indexed (combine-with + a) b)
```

Just need to wait for 1.8 for the performance: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1553

Here are some timings on a 6 core CPU:

```
(def irange (vec (range (count a))))  ; precompute

(c/quick-bench (def ab (r/foldcat (r/map #(+ (a %) (b %)) irange))))
             Execution time mean : 1.426060 ms

(c/quick-bench (def abt (into [] (map-indexed (combine-with + a)) b)))
             Execution time mean : 9.931824 ms
```